# I can't create ipa file, when i try to archive

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

When i try to archive it show Distribute content but in before it shows distribute app.

[image]

Comment: Since Version and Identifier are blank, you're probably doing something wrong when archiving it. Are you getting any warnings?

Comment: I do not get any warnings , even i can run in my mobile, yes may be i mistake some where, in before it will work. but what actually mistake I can't found

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, If any one mistake such like will help for him.

just go to your main project target -> Skip install is NO

Comment: I don´t understand your solution. Where do yo go exactly? I don't find this 'Skip install' option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

one can create the ipa only for the application and from the screen shot it looks like you are not building iOS mobile app, the target of you you project is other then the mobile app, its a framework, so for framework you can not export ipa file,
 as the framework will not work as standalone app it will go inside other app ipa,

hope you understood

check one more things if you have multiple target under your project then please check the right target to build it must me a an app not framework

Thanks

Comment: I try to include my own create framework in my project but I also remove that framework.  is there any way to run this project as a app?

Comment: What all  targets you have in your project ? to run it as an app you need to add a right target in the project.